# ASP.Net MVC Search Form persist search options after post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently developing an application which offers the user the ability to search on a list of accounts based on 3 search parameters (AccountID, Account Name and County), this allows the user to narrow down the list of accounts they are dealing with.

A typical search the users would perform is if they are say disabling a set off accounts within a County, this would be done by selecting the County and clicking the search button.  They can then click on the details link in the presented list and make the update, this works fine however what I would like to then do is redirect the user back to the original search maintaining the search parameters (e.g. the county) and if possible rerunning the query.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could achieve this?

Thanks In Advance.

Stuart

Comment: can you post some code of controller .. how search you have implemented???

Comment: as far as i m understanding your requirement just put your search parameters and required thing in tempdata and then retrieve it after one redirect also..

Comment: you can define a class Search(AccountID,AccountName,Country) and you put this class in the Session each time the user inquiry the search, and when the user update the details, you can reload the search page which will read the session and put in ViewBag.SearchData, and in the view, you will set the values of the text boxes and drop downs using the ViewBag.SearchData

Answer (score 0):

Like Hadi said, a good solution would be to save the search criteria to the session.
Assuming the search criteria are input parameters to the action, you need a way to decide whether to use the input parameters, or the previously stored criteria. I chose to use an optional boolean to determine this.

```
// The data structure that is stored to the session
class SearchCriteria
{
    public int? AccountId;
    public string AccountName;
    public string County;

    public SearchCriteria(int? accountId, string accountName, string county)
    {
        AccountId = accountId;
        AccountName = accountName;
        County = county;
    }

}

 public class SearchResultViewModel
{
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public List<string> Counties { get; set; }
    public bool AlterCriteria { get; set; }

    public List<Entity> SearchResultEntities { get; set; } 

}

public ActionResult SearchResult(SearchResultViewModel model)
    {

        ....

        // The search should use the search criteria that is stored in the session
        if (!model.AlterCriteria)
        {
            // Attempt to retrieve from session
            var searchCriteria = Session["searchCriteria"] as SearchCriteria;

            // Use previous search criteria if any
            if (searchCriteria != null)
            {
                query.AccountId = searchCriteria.AccountId;
                query.AccountName = searchCriteria.AccountName;
                query.County = searchCriteria.County;
            }

        }
            // Provided input should be used as search criteria
        else
        {
            // Saved to session
            var searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria(model.AccountId, model.AccountName, model.County);
            Session["searchCriteria"] = searchCriteria;
        }


        model.Counties = Database.GetCounties();

        model.SearchResultEntities = Database.GetEntities(query);

        return View(model);

    }
```

SearchResult.cshtml:

```
@model SearchResultViewModel

@Html.BeginForm("SearchResult"){

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AlterCriteria, new { @Value = true })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountId)    
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.County, new SelectList(Model.Counties))

.........
```

}

.......

With this code, any call to SearchResult (for instance a redirect) would use the previously saved search criteria, while calls to change the search filter would need to include the alterCriteria = true parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @fiskeboss, looks exactly like what I need, one other question, how do i ensure the form fields from the search form are repopulated including one which is a drop down list?

Comment: You would add them to your ViewModel and use Razor to populate the form fields. I have no idea what your code looks like, but an almost complete solution could look something like this (editing the original post, note the change to the input parameters of the SearchResult action)